# Coordinates transformation from MGI 31276 to WGS84

Tags: coordinate-system, arcmap, basemap

[image]

I have a shapefile in MGI 31276/Balkan zone 6, and it doesn't line up with my base map.

I try to make transformation from MGI 31276 to WGS 1984 Web Mercator Auxiliary Sphere, but it's impossible, and and I don't know why.

Comment: which software are you using? why is it impossible - can you give more detail/error messages/procedure used?

Comment: Im using ArcMap 10. 4; I posted a photo which procedure i used, thank you

Comment: I did transformation with copy features (change coordinates system in enviroments),  but shp is still "on the same place", didnt move. I need to make it to line up with basemap, but nothing

Comment: Done right, data reprojection **shouldn't** result in a change to the map canvas, since the map projects it right back.

Comment: Basemap is in  WGS 1984 Web Mercator Auxiliary Sphere, and shp (MGI 31276/Balkan zone 6) doesnt line up with it. I think after dat reprojection shp shoul line up with basemap, but it isnt.

Comment: If the projection of your basemap and layer are properly defined then arcmap take care of on the fly reprojection to align them so as Vince said reprojecting yourself wont change anything. That being said ArcMap offer some option for reprojecting : go to the "coordinate system" tab of the data frame properties and click on the "transformation" button to check if you have some different reprojection method. if you can't fix it this way it's either that your data have a wrong CRS defined or they where digitized on a reference that didn't align with your basemap.